# Use facebook to vote on pictures on website

Tags: facebook, voting

I am planning on making a website where there will be a couple of photo's on it on which people can vote.

I would like to want to use Facebook for voting, so that on the website the user chooses his/her favorite picture and when he votes, he will start a facebook application so the user is identified. His vote will be stored in my database, together with a userid, so he can't vote twice. User can choose to update his wall with the vote.

I know this is possible, and I know how to make facebook apps. However I don't seem to find a way to make this accessible from the website.

So the short question:
How can I create a facebook application that will be called from a website and gives a signal back after adding the vote to the database?

Thanks

Comment: Ironically, before Mark Zuckerberg invented Facebook, he had a similar idea from which Facebook was born. He gathered the photos through a script, though...

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the whole process into your Facebook application, which means that you have to put the images in the app too. It's the only way to get a callback on the user votes. Have a look at some vote your style apps in Facebook which are working the same way.